# Magento 2 : Layout Processor won't Load Model

Tags: magento2, layout, shipping-address, plugin

I have a layout processor, for adding dropdown with value from model database. When I try to define model in Layout Processor, the page goes blank and only showing the gif loading circle, heres my custom code:

```
namespace Test\Hello\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{


    public function afterProcess(
            \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
            array  $jsLayout,
            \Lime\Courier\Model\YeezysFactory $yeezyModel
        ) {
           $yeezyz = $yeezyModel->create()->getCollection();

           foreach ($yeezyz as $yeezy) {
             $opt[] = array(
                   'value' => $yeezy['yeezy_id'],
                   'label' => $yeezy['name']
               );
           }
          $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['yeezy'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'yeezy',
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.yeezy',
                    'label' => 'Drop Down',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => false,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'sortOrder' => 254,
                    'id' => 'yeezy',
                    'options' =>  $opt;
                ];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move following line from afterProcess to __construct

```
\Lime\Courier\Model\YeezysFactory $yeezyModel
```

Now your code looks like

```
namespace Test\Hello\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
    protected $yeezyModel;
    public function __construct(
        \Lime\Courier\Model\YeezysFactory $yeezyModel
    ) {
        $this->yeezyModel = $yeezyModel
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $yeezyz = $this->yeezyModel->create()->getCollection();

        foreach ($yeezyz as $yeezy) {
            $opt[] = array(
                'value' => $yeezy['yeezy_id'],
                'label' => $yeezy['name']
            );
        }
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['yeezy'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'yeezy',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.yeezy',
            'label' => 'Drop Down',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => false,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 254,
            'id' => 'yeezy',
            'options' =>  $opt;
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to access 'id' => 'yeezy' or any parameter in html template. How can i access it in html file? Can you please tell me?